# How to get a single index from a DataSet in PyTorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

I want to randomly draw a sample from my test DataSet object to perform a prediction using my trained model.

To achieve this I use this code block which causes the following error:

```
rng = np.random.default_rng()
ind = rng.integers(0,len(test_ds),(1,))[-1]


I = test_ds[ind] # Note I is a list of tensors of equal size
I = [Ik.to(device) for Ik in I]

with torch.no_grad():
      _, y_f_hat, _, y_f = model.forward_F(I)
      y_f_hat = y_f_hat.cpu().numpy().flatten()
      y_f = y_f.cpu().numpy().flatten()
```

```
ERROR: /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/flatten.py in forward(self, input)
     44 
     45     def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:
---> 46         return input.flatten(self.start_dim, self.end_dim)
     47 
     48     def extra_repr(self) -> str:

IndexError: Dimension out of range (expected to be in range of [-1, 0], but got 1)
```

There is no problem when using the dataloader:

```
for I in test_dataloader:
  with torch.no_grad():
      _, y_f_hat, _, y_f = model.forward_F(I)
      y_f_hat = y_f_hat.cpu().numpy().flatten()
      y_f = y_f.cpu().numpy().flatten()
      break
```

test_ds is the dataset used in test_dataloader.

Notes: on google Colab GPU, Python 3.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `DataLoader`, it brings the data as a batch of samples. So the shape of the data coming out of `DataLoader` is like `(B, ...)` where `B` is the batch size and `...` are the other dimensions (I do not know how your samples look like, in terms of images, for example, it is like `(B, C, H, W)` where `C, H, W` are the number of channels, height and width, respectively). This is what pytorch layers expect. In other words, you need a preceding dimension for batch size.

As a solution, you can call `.unsqueeze(0)` on input tensor before feeding into the model.

```py
_, y_f_hat, _, y_f = model.forward_F(I.unsqueeze(0))
```